# Import data from csv

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I am new on Drupal. I have a csv where I want to upload on a drupal site every week.

I tried to follow this tutorial [enter link description here](http://fuzion.co.nz/content/getting-your-csv-data-drupal-view-using-feeds-data-ready-migrate) but "Data Processor" doesn't show. I have installed all the modules and clear the cache.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i read in an [issue in feeds](https://drupal.org/node/1420490#comment-5530270)  that:

> The Data processor was removed from Feeds in 7.x because Alex was unsure of the future of the data module. Seeing as there's a release of data for 7.x, it makes sense to revive it.

but if you need to implement it manually i guess this [comment](https://drupal.org/node/1420490#comment-6926040) will help.

Comment: Thank you. I thought maybe there was another module that can make the same procedure. But I believe this will work too.